# Jquery: Dropdownmenu Problems Getting Div to stay once open and mouseover, it closes before i can even put my mouse into it

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jquery, as in about a month times in...I under the coding, but I am still having problems piecing this project together. I am trying to create a dropdown menu that when I put my mouse over the link a hidden  is shown and then i want to be able to browsing into that div, when i try to put my mouse into that div it closes and will not stay open because I have taken my mouse off of the link. How do I keep the div open to browse?

link to project http://www.nestudiosonline.com/test.php

The jquery;

```
// JavaScript Document

$(document).ready(function() {
    // shows the hidden div  
    $('#about').mouseover(function() {
        $('#aboutdke').css('display','block');
        return false;
    });
    // hides the hide the div again 
    $('#about').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#aboutdke').css('display','none');
        return false;
    });
});
```

I know there should be more to the code but i just cant figure it out. Thanksssss

Comment: you have mouseleave on about , change it to the div which you are showing when mouseover about....///that should fix it ,

Comment: @gov - you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // shows the hidden div  
    $('#about').mouseover(function() {
        $('#aboutdke').show();
        return false;// there is no need of return false here
    });
    // hides the hide the div again 
    $('#changeit to the sub menu id').mouseleave(function() {
        $('#aboutdke').hide();
        return false; // there is no need of return false here
    });
});
```

user jquery hover intent plugin its very nice to add delays also

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Comment: @dave , use jquery .show() and hide() instead of css...display block and none ,it will be more cleaner

Comment: okay so now it stays, and when i take my mouse off it hides, however i want it to hide as well when i take my mouse off of about, because if i dont do that it will stay open.

Comment: @dave it should be very easy , make a boolean variable and default it false , whenyou mouseout from first one check boolean variable if it is false hide it , if user mouseover the submenu make the boolean variable true...

Comment: i dont get why i would make a boolean, i can make one but im telling it to check if im off of #about to see if #aboutdke is hidden or shown and if its shown then on mouseleave of #about hide #aboutdke? also the background color of #about doesnt stay highlighted when i go into aboutdke, lorddddd shoot mee

Comment: @dave , see this example , he has explanation too , http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/mega-drop-downs-w-css-jquery/

Comment: @dave one more simple example....http://www.queness.com/preview/1047/easy-to-style-jquery-drop-down-menu-tutorial